# How do I make website labels Right to left, It is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, localization, right-to-left, blazor

I built a website using MVC Core and Bootstrap 4, It is right to left and for example its form labels begin from right. I created a Blazor Website and copied bootstrap.min.js and a form from MVC core site, and applied direction="rtl" and dir="rtl" to Blazor Body and other elements, but the Labels texts still begin from left.
I also tried  flex-direction: column-reverse; and  flex-direction: row-reverse; that did not made site right to left. What is the problem here?

```
<div class="card" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 70%;background-color: lightgray; ">
<div class="card-header">@login</div>
<div class="card-block m-1 p-2">
    <EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
        <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="returnUrl" />
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user">@user</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" id="user" bind-Value="@Model.User" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">@password</label>
            <InputText Id="password" class="form-control" bind-Value="@Model.Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <InputCheckbox Id="rememberMe" bind-value="@Model.RememberMe" />&nbsp;@rememberMe
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">@login</button>
        <br /><br />
        <NavLink class="nav-link" style="display:inline;" href="/account/register">
            @register
        </NavLink>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <NavLink class="nav-link" style="display:inline;" href="/account/requestpasswordreset">
            @forgotPassword
        </NavLink>
    </EditForm>
    <label style="color: @(Model.Success ? "green" : "red")">@Model.Message</label>
    @if (!AsyncSuccess)
    {
        <label style="color: red;">@*Async method or Network Error.*@  @asyncError</label>
    }
    @if (AjaxLoading)
    {
        <img width="80" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    }
</div>
@*<label>@Model.Token</label>*@
```

With this form and applying rtl to any level above it, The labels texts begin from left.

Comment: Please show some code of what you are doing so that people can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying RTL directionality at the document or wrapper level won't change the way Bootstrap positions its elements.

Try using [Bootstrap-RTL](https://github.com/MahdiMajidzadeh/bootstrap-v4-rtl) instead of the standard Bootstrap.

Comment: But it is working in my MVC Core website, and all labels texts begin from right side.

Comment: I temporarily replaced bootstrap and its js with RTL Version and cleared browser cache and reload that still labels are left to right, Also I applied rtl to any level up to the body and added style rule label{direction: rtl; width: 100%;} and also set flex-direction to column-reverse and row-reverse, still is left to right, I think this bug is related to Blazor's <EditForm> component that internally makes the form inside it Left to Right!